# Vue.js props not showing proper image

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vue-component

I need a dynamic menu bar for my project with changing icons which are added as image. In my Menu.vue component i added a variable for img src called iconPath.

```
<img id="main" :src="iconPath">
```

When using the Menu.vue component at the parent component like so:

```
<Menu iconPath="../assets/plusIcon.png"></Menu>
```

it doesn't show my icon, just a little square with a image icon inside, even if the right path is given as the dev tools show.

**Icon that is shown:**
[image]

**Dev tools that show the right icon path for props:**
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to right click on that displayed broken image and choose open image in new tab or something? it will show the path it is trying to load from.

Comment: this is the address it shows when right clicking on it http://localhost:8080/assets/searchIcon.png

Comment: You've given it a relative path. But it's relative to current page's route, not to the component location in the project. The browser has no knowledge of your internal component and project structure. Look in the console and you'll see at least one `404` error from the image not being found. Look closely at where it's trying to load the image from and adjust your path so it loads from the actual location.

Comment: Most probably, you need to append a `/src` to the path. as in: `/src/assets/plusIcon.png`.

Comment: unfortunately I can't find any 404 error... and the /src didn't change anything...